# htaccess rewrite rule to redirect particular url style

Tags: .htaccess

help please,

I have a rule in my htaccess file,

RewriteRule ^.+/.+.?-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?act=displayimg&id=$1 [L]

and it works fine for the below url
http://www.cvbcvb.com/anytext/any-text-here-too-1287.html

**What I need is a htaccess rule for the below style url**

http://www.cvbcvb.com/any-text-here/any-text-here/any-text-714.html

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on


###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l




############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none


ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?act=404

RewriteRule ^.+\-([0-9]+)\/index\.html$ index.php?act=categories&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.+\-([0-9]+)\/index([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?act=categories&id=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^tags\/(.+)\.html$ index.php?act=search&terms=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tags\/(.+)\.html\&page\=([0-9]+)$ index.php?act=search&terms=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^.+\/.+.?\-([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?act=wallpaper&id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^wallpapers\/download.?([0-9]+).?([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)\..+$ index.php?act=downloads&id=$1&x=$2&y=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^users\/(.+)\.html$ index.php?act=user&mode=view_user&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login\.html$ index.php?act=user&mode=login [L]
RewriteRule ^forgot\.html$ index.php?act=user&mode=forgot [L]
RewriteRule ^login\/(.+)\.html$ index.php?act=user&mode=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user\/$ index.php?act=user&mode=home [L]
RewriteRule ^user\/(.+)\.html$ index.php?act=user&mode=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user\/gallery\/(.+)\/([0-9]+)\/$ index.php?act=user&mode=$1&wallid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^user\/message\/([0-9]+)\/$ index.php?act=user&mode=show_message&mid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user\/reply\/([0-9]+)\/$ index.php?act=user&mode=reply_message&mid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^users\/(.+)\.html$ index.php?act=user&mode=view_user&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^users\/reply\/([0-9]+)\/$ index.php?act=user&mode=user_comment&uid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^signup\.html$ index.php?act=user&mode=signup [L]
RewriteRule ^contact\.php$ index.php?act=contact [L]
RewriteRule ^search\.html$ index.php?act=search [L]
RewriteRule ^disabled\.html$ index.php?act=disabled [L]
RewriteRule ^submit\.html$ index.php?act=user&mode=guest_submit [L]
RewriteRule ^top\_wallpaper([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?act=categories&mode=top&id=$1&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^latest\_wallpaper([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?act=categories&mode=latest&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^searchSuggest\-(.+)\.php$ index.php?act=searchSuggest&search=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.+\/filter\/index([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?act=categories&mode=filter&id=$1&page=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.+\/filter\/index([0-9]+)\_([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?act=categories&mode=filter&id=$1&page=$2 [L]

<Files ~ "\.cphp">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*?/.*?/(.*?)\.html$ http://www.windowswallpaper.com/3d-15/flower/$1.html
```

Comment: Could you provide why? I will fix it so it does.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know why, I bought this a long time ago and there is no support live now. For some reason Google is sending a wrong url to  my website. The url Supposed to be in this format http://www.cvbcvb.com/anytext/any-text-here-too-1287.html but the google send the traffic to this format http://www.cvbcvb.com/any-text-here/any-text-here/any-text-714.html

Comment: Some how my answer got corrupted, try with the new example...Also, did you use RewriteEngine On?

Comment: Tried it still no luck, you can see the problem at http://www.windowswallpaper.com/3d-15/flower/holland-tulip-festival-michigan-1287.html as I said the (3d-15/) should not be there in the url and I have no idea how google picked it up. If you remove (3d-15/) you can see it works fine.

Comment: Ok, try now! Worked on my end.

Comment: Post your entire htaccess file please.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow how to attach a file here?

Comment: edit your original post, highlight the new content, click the { } icon to make it code and update.

Comment: I guess the line responsible is RewriteRule ^.+\/.+.?\-([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?act=wallpaper&id=$1 [L]